# Python pandas function to roll data from previous week to current week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

[image]

Every week I get new data. For example, in week 1 I have data from Jan & Feb, in week 2 I have data for Feb and March, and week 3 I have from March April.

The requirement is, in week 2 when there is no data for Jan, we want to copy data of the previous week Jan number to current week. Similarly, in week 3 if there is no data for Jan or Feb we need to copy from previous latest week so that the data looks like this:

[image]

The new months may add up in the future so we need to copy the latest week data rolling to next week.

Is there a Pandas function to do this rolling data?

Where the columns in the current week have missing values for some months, that particular month's values need to be copied to future weeks on a rolling basis and account for new months in addition to being based on the categorical columns.

Comment: I think you mean something like the following: `df.iloc[:, 3:] = df.groupby(["Cat_1", "Cat_2", "Cat_3"]).ffill()`?  This will group by category, and then forward will the values.

Comment: so the .iloc function does the job if I have to do it just ffill and the numbers dont change, but see in feb the week 2 values changes from 2,3 to 3,2, so the latest week number only has to be copied, so there may be scenario's like this per categories. In this case this logic wont work

Comment: That line of code will forward fill with `3, 2` (and **not** `2, 3`) in the following weeks, as shown in your image.  I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: That should also be grouped by week?

Comment: No need to group by week, as you are just forward filling from the last value, from what I understand.  Therefore, as long as the data is sorted by week first, it can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't a scalable approach to modeling real-world data.

[Hadley Wickham](https://hadley.nz) would counsel you to
[tidy](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf)
up your dataset so that "each variable is a column, each observation is a row,
and each type of observational unit is a table."
You have the last part nailed already.

Now, I understand that you may be drawing this dataframe
from a similarly formatted spreadsheet, which has month-name headings,
and that you may need to write a
[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or
[pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
to put it back in that format for others to review
if that's what they're accustomed to.
But right now we need to
[melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
that untidy spreadsheet so it is a sensible
[relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)).

You have a triple of `cat_{1,2,3}` columns.
The cats are very nice, they are all needed.
But the `week` column, taking on values `1` .. `5`, is not terrific.
The thing about apples and oranges, I mean about months and weeks,
is that they're pretty independent from each other.
A given month could start on any of the seven possible week days,
and have some variable number of weeks.

Your **business** generates new observations on a weekly schedule.
Let's respect that when we model the data.

The [.isocalendar()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.isocalendar.html)
function returns an (isoyear, isoweek, DoW) triple.
You can discard that final day-of-week,
as it will be constant in your use case.
Many businesses choose to have Monday start the week,
so figures from both weekend days will conveniently appear together.

Now we have a compound
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key)
of `(isoyear, isoweek, cats)`, and the PK maps to a single value, good.
It will be convenient to store a 2nd attribute,
an ordinary `date` column, for later reporting.
Likely it will always be a "Monday" date.
Note that `date.dt.year` will sometimes differ from `isoyear`.

You didn't put any effort into making your problem
[reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),
so we see no code that could be adapted to this new representation.

> Is there a pandas function to do this rolling data ?

Given a tidy relation as described,
it is easy to loop over {months, weeks} to fill in
the reporting values you require.

tl;dr: The way you choose to *represent* original source data
may differ from the way you *report* on it.